# Node JS/Express: Check that login has succeeded

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, access-token

I have a button on 'index.html' that opens a new tab to a Spotify login page. The new tab gets an authorization code and creates/sets an access token in my app.js so I can make requests to the Spotify API. It then closes itself after it succeeds, which brings us back to 'index.html'.

I want to change the contents of 'index.html' once the login succeeds and the login tab closes itself. How can I check if a login has happened yet, and how do I update 'index.html' once it has happened?

Comment: You need to review Spotify's API documentation to be sure that you receive a proper answer. After, if you received the righ answer, what dou you want to update into your index.html?

Comment: @andresmunozit I’m already getting information that the login is being verified and I’m getting an access token; I just want to be able to check for when this event has occurred in index.html.

Comment: Please, be clear when you say "how do I update 'index.html' once it has happened?", what do you want to update?. Also "check for when this event has occurred in index.html" how do you want to notify index.html? With a global state variable? With the actual data received from Spotifi's API?... With that little amount of information I'd recommend you to save the data received from Spotify's API in a  localStorage variable (Warning: Do not save credentials or API Keys there) Then, when the focus returns to the `Index.html` tab, re read that `localStorage` variable. Use the `Page Visibility API`

Comment: I wasn’t really sure how I wanted to check that the event had happened in my Express code so I was asking for recommendations. I’ve never heard of the Page Visibility API, I will definitely look into it, thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

A page (index.html) which opens a new tab always have a handle to the newly opened window.

```
let authWindow = window.open('https://spotify.com');
```

And add a setInterval to look for the accessToken in localStorage api. So once a accessToken value is saved, the authWindow handler will close the newly opened window.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if(localStorage && localStorage.get("accessToken"))
         authWindow.close();
}, 1000);
```

On the spotify window, save the returned authToken into localStorage.

```
localStorage.set("accessToken","tokenvalue");
```